# Need a Batch script to get the PID of the process responsible to open the file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch script where I need to grep the Process which is responsible to open the file and then store the PID of that process in variable
and kill it completely.

Comment: PID of the process responsible for opening *which* file?

Comment: [Read a similar question](http://superuser.com/q/875770/376602). However, how do you want to identify _the Process which is responsible to open the file_? Cf. comment by @rojo

Comment: I always get an error "output_MU-Measures-CQM2015-Tests.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.."   then I always search the file "output_MU-Measures-CQM2015-Tests.xml" through process explore and get the PID of that process which is using this file and then kill the process.I need a batch script through which I can find the process PID (process which is using that file) and kill that process.

Comment: Use [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx)

Comment: `handle output_MU-Measures-CQM2015-Tests.xml|find /I "pid:"` gives exactly required info, easy parsable with `for /F` [against a command loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Thank you @ziddarth for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to complete a similar task

```
echo off
FOR /F %%T IN ('Wmic process where^(Name^="Console.exe"^)get ProcessId^|more +1') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo Killing Process at PID= %ProcessId%   
taskkill /F /PID %ProcessId%  
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Replace Console.exe with the task the you want to kill. Console.exe is the process name that you would see in taskmanager.

As a side note this will kill the first instance that if can find of "Console.exe" So if you have more than one of the processes running it will only kill the first one.

There is a really nice tool ([Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)) created that allows you to right click a file with a filelock and choose unlock and the tool releases the filelock.

Comment: I'd not run it in virtue of: 1. is the file locked always by the same process name? And if so, then 2. is _the first instance_ really that one which has locked the file in question?

Comment: Yes I always found that java.exe process lock the file and then I killed that java.exe process but one more important thing is there are another java.exe process runs.I always kill that one which is associated with that file(search the process with the filename and use the PID of that process to kill that process only)